# JSRender how to access variable outside the block

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsrender

I am using a jsrender to show the details of my json object.
  I am wondering how I can access the outside variable inside the list.
  Thank you.

```
   <script id="itemTemplate" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">

            {{=outsideVariable}} //STRING
            <div id="receipt_list_container">
                {{#each receiptSummary.receipts}}  //LIST
                    {{=formattedMonth}}
                                //HOW CAN I ACCESS THE OUTSIDE THE VARIABLE
                {{/each}}
            </div>

    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, this is your example: [Example Scenario: Accessing parent data.](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/11_accessing-parent-data.html)

```
var model = {
    specialMessage: function(...) { ... },
    theater: "Rialto",
    movies: [ ... ]
}

{{for movies}}
    <tr>
        <td>'{{>title}}': showing at the '{{>#parent.parent.data.theater}}'</td>
```

Comment: {{#each}} instead of {{for}}.. It works on the new jsrender.. but how can i make it work using the old jsrender

Comment: what is the equivalent of this in the old jsrender? --> {{>#parent.parent.data.theater}}

Comment: @newbie I work with new JSRender, can you create jsfiddle.net example with you version?

Comment: i think the tag should be different.. do you have any idea what is the equivalence of this tag in the old jsrender version.. {{>#parent.parent.data.theater}

Comment: the version of our jsrender  is "v1.0pre"

Comment: JSFIDDLE sample --> jsfiddle.net/6425U/8

Comment: @newbie are you sure that you post right url? In this `jsfiddle.net/6425U/8` you add local resource. Note that last code also is `v1.0pre` http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/jsrender.js

Comment: Your example throw error `Unmatched or missing tag: "{{/each}}" in template` http://jsfiddle.net/6425U/10/

Comment: @newbie Look at this code `https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/issues/49`, as I can see you need `$`

Comment: @newbie here is answer on your question (http://sixohthree.com/1799/jsrender-passing-variables-to-nested-templates), if your version really support `each`.